# Why does no current flow when GND of one battery is connected to VCC of other battery?

Tags: current, basic, electricity

I have enough experience with electronics to design and solder working circuits. I never quite understood though why circuits must be closed for current to flow.

I alway understood electrical current as the movement of charged particles (free electrons usually in circuits), from a ‘high pressure’ region to a ‘lower pressure’ region.

But by that analogy I never could comprehend why no current flows when the - pole of one battery is connected to the + pole of another battery?

Please don’t say “because the circuit isn’t closed”. It’s exactly what I’d like to understand - on a physical level - why the circuit must be closed (especially when understanding electrical current as the flow of charged particles from high-density to low density)

Comment: Are you aware that the net electrical charge on each battery is zero and remains zero throughout its life? What you are proposing is that charge flows from one battery into another thereby leaving one with an overall negative charge and the other with a positive. This will not happen. The closed circuit is required so that charge in equals charge out.

Comment: Just because you have a high voltage, and possibly a high electric field, unless there is ARCING thru the air, no current will flow.

Comment: @Transistor & analogsystemsrf correct, but these still are no *explanations* though as to why electrons flow when the circuit is closed, but don’t when gnd of one battery is connected tovcc of another.

Comment: When you connect the two batteries as you describe there is no potential difference between the connected terminals (they are at the same potential due to the connection) so there is no electromotive force to move charge.

Comment: @transistor is there a short current then to equalize then?

Comment: Nope, no current. The only exception would be if there is significant capacitance to ground between both devices but then you have a closed circuit for current to flow around until the capacitance voltages equalise.